# How to make one validation error for 2 fields

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 fields for postal code main and sub.

```
<input type="text" name="postal01">
<input type="text" name="postal02">
```

I would like to have validation for numeric and size of both fields added.
What I want to do is showing validation error for one field as postal_cd, not each field error.

I had tried in a request class extended FormRequest.

```
class MemberRequest extends FormRequest
{
  public function all($keys = null)
  {
    $result = parent::all($keys);

    if($this->filled('postal01') && $this->filled('postal02')) {
        $results['postal_code'] = $this->input('postal01') . $this->input('postal02');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

However it did not work like I expected.

How can I handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an **After Validation Hook**. Add the following to your Form Request:

```
/**
* Configure the validator instance.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
* @return void
*/
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if($validator->errors()->has('postal01') || $validator->errors()->has('postal02')) {
            $validator->errors()->add('postal_cd', 'Please enter a postal code');
        }
    });
}
```

... and then to display it on your blade:

```
{{ $errors->first('postal_cd') }}
```

Comment: Where this function is supposed to be called? It does not seems to work for me.

Comment: You don't call it. You just need to add it to your Form Request.

Comment: Do I need to put rules for postal01 and postal02 in order to occur the errors?

Comment: Yep, you would put your rules as they were. The hook will check if the errors exist in your validator instance and add a new one under the key `postal_cd`. In your blade file you would just output whatever is in your `postal_cd`.

Comment: Thanks. However What if I need to treat each field is no error, but both field total size are error, how can I handle it? For examples, 5 digit is allowed for each, but total 10 is not allowed on both fields? Can I let you figure out what I mean?

Comment: Since the After Validation Hook is working with a Validator Instance, you could retrieve the fields with `$validator->getData()` and apply your logic from there.

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean. See [this.](https://implode.io/mj1mv5)

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure out.

Comment: What I don't figure out is how to show the messages. I would like to set message defined in function messages() as the other fields do. I don't deeply understand these structures. I need more time.

Comment: You can keep your `messages()` as it is. An after validation hook is just basically adding more responsibilities to the validator instance. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#after-validation-hook)

Comment: I wonder why I don't go with it. The message I wrote in func 'withValidator()' get priority than func 'message()'.

Comment: I am confused as to what you want. Feel free to unmark this answer as the right one.

Comment: rules() 'postal01'=>'size:3', 'postal02'=>'size:4' / messages() 'postal_code.size' => 'This should be displayed!!'

Answer (score 0):

That was my typo.

```
class MemberRequest extends FormRequest
{
  public function all($keys = null)
  {
    $result = parent::all($keys);

    if($this->filled('postal01') && $this->filled('postal02')) {
      $result['postal_code'] = $this->input('postal01') . $this->input('postal02');
   // $results['postal_code'] = $this->input('postal01') . $this->input('postal02');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Returned value should have been $result. But it was typo $results['postal_code'].
It works.